# Objective-C - What are some uses of the NSProxy class?

Tags: objective-c, nsproxy

What are some uses of the NSProxy class. Why would you want to be able to have the description of an object that doesn't exist?

Comment: Naturally you've read [the relevant documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/Concepts/connections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000761-96933); can you make your question more specific?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The NSProxy class provides a basic implementation of a class whose instances are used to stand in for other objects. We need NSProxy to implement transparent distributed messaging or for lazy instantiation of object.
[NSProxy Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProxy_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[Distributed object programming topics](http://pooh.poly.asu.edu/Cst502/Resources/ObjectiveC/AppleDistrObjects.pdf)

Comment: I'd say because you copy-pasted the doc, which anyone can find on Google. A personalized answer with example use cases would be appreciated, but this answer has already been accepted.

Answer (score -1):

An `NSProxy` is an object that forwards messages to an object on a different thread, in a different process, or even on a different host.  Read the documentation on Distributed Objects.

Comment: So you can't use NSProxy for anything else than Distributed Objects?

Comment: NSProxy is the means by which distributed objects are implemented.  It has no other purpose.